# C++ initializing object and allocating memory

Tags: c++, class, oop

I have a struct like :

```
struct myNode{
    Node node; // node object takes just name parameter I mean node(string name);
    int value;
};
```

And In my main() function, I have a struct myNode pointer and I want to first read a file to get the name of node object and value(just an integer)  then create my corresponding struct myNode. To do that, I write

```
int main(){
    struct myNode * myRoot;
    ifstream myfile (fileName);
    string line;
    getline(myfile,line);
int value=getValue(line);
myRoot= new myNode();
    myRoot->value=value;
myRoot->node=node a(line);

  return 0;    
}
```

However,I'm not sure, is it the correct way or not, is there anyone to help me ?

Comment: Where's `Node` defined? Show us more.

Comment: Also, `node a(line);` is very suspicious

Comment: From what you show us it seems ok to me. I guess that `myRoot->node = node a(line)` is `Node a(line)` (Node not node)

Comment: even in case of a struct i would prefer a constructor. i.e. myNode( int val, Node n ) : value(val), node(n) {}. You can use it like: myRoot = new MyNode(value, a(line)); // whatever a(line) may be.

Comment: @EoiFirst: No, it isn't. `a` is an undefined identifier. Perhaps `myRoot->node=Node(line)` is appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can work except:

1. You forget to delete myRoot before function main exit. Yes, os can recycle it when your programe exit, but you can make your code more graceful.
2. `myRoot->node= node a(line)` can just be `myRoot->node = Node(line)` or `myRoot->node = line` if struct Node's constructor can take line as the only parameter. I suppose you treat *a* as a temp instance of Node.

Comment: _myRoot->node = line if struct Node's constructor can take line as the only parameter_ - No! Since the construction of `myRoot->node` is already happened, having such a constructor won't help. It'll only work if there's an assignment operator taking a `string` or `Node` itself is a `string`.

Comment: @legends2k Sorry, I missed something. If there has a operator= which takes line or another instance of Node, it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Among the many deadly issues in your code, the one I see that must be giving you the most trouble is the one on this line:

```
myRoot->node = node a(line);
```

The `node a(line)` part is a syntax error. I believe you meant it to be:

```
myRoot->node = node(line);
```

or, if `Node` doesn't have an `explicit` constructor:

```
myRoot->node = line;
```

The other deadly issues are the fact that you're using pointers, allocating with `new` (both of which are unnecessary options) and that you're performing extraction on the file stream without checking if it works. All of these things can be resolved by allocating objects on the stack and checking if the input succeeded:

```
int main()
{
    myNode myRoot;
    ifstream myfile(fileName);
    string line;

    if (getline(myfile, line))
    {
        int value = getValue(line);
        myRoot.value = value;
        myRoot.node  = line;
    }    
}
```